# How to Get Hidden Input Value in JQuery 1.10.2 Ajax variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm create Rating System using JavaScript when user select the star value set value in hidden input type. now i want to get that value in my ajax code and post to database.

I am try this way to get value of input

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajaxSetup({
                 headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 }
             });
              $.ajax({
                 url: "/review",
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                    description: $('textarea[name=description]').val(),
                    star: $('input:hidden[name=score]').val(),
                    user_id: {{Auth::user()->id}},
                    product_id: {{$product->id}}
                 },
                 dataType: "JSON",
                 success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                 }
                });
              });
           });
```

in actual file that code show

```
<div class="star big" id="rating" data-score="0"></div>
```

After Select the Star that code show in Resource

```
<div class="star big" id="rating" data-score="0" style="cursor: pointer; width: 80px;"><img src="assets/images/star-big-on.png" alt="1" title="bad">
<img src="assets/images/star-big-on.png" alt="2" title="poor">
<img src="assets/images/star-big-on.png" alt="3" title="regular">
<img src="assets/images/star-big-on.png" alt="4" title="good">
<img src="assets/images/star-big-on.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous">
<input id="star" type="hidden" name="score" value="5"></div>
```

star value null show in result

Comment: console Result {star: null,}

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector for the element seems correct, but I believe that your javascript data object is incorrect. You use blade syntax in an object, so you should most probably surround it with quotes. Specifically I am talking about this two lines:

```
user_id: "{{Auth::user()->id}}",
product_id: "{{$product->id}}"
```

And I believe that you are using this within a blade view and not in a `.js` file.

Comment: i'm using in before body close tage and same file every thing is correct they get user_id, product_id and description vlaue just star value not get.

Comment: And in the developer console if you try on the same page to call `$('input:hidden[name=score]').val()` do you get the correct value? I am talking about the browser developer console.

Comment: You can also try `$('#star').val();` as you already have an ID there, but I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: I'm try both browser console result is same. this hidden input filed have in other js file but i'm using ajax code in same html file

Comment: Console Result {description: "ssssss", star: null, user_id: "2", product_id: "1"}description: "ssssss"product_id: "1"star: nulluser_id: "2"__proto__: Object

Comment: does the html element exists in the same file as your JS script?

Comment: <input id="star" type="hidden" name="score" value="5"> is in JS file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191787/discussion-between-nakov-and-rana-raheel-tariq).